# AngularJS - Issues passing attributes to directive - Receive undefined value for each of them

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I´m working on a directive that receives four parameters, each of them is binded to the directive scope.

The issue is that the directive receives all the values as undefined, the data exists, and it´s loaded. I thought about the async loading of data, but, "page" isn´t async, and it´s published in the scope from the very beginning.

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4NEciJZBFZOdJZqR1V6D

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <itemscounter offset="dataObject.offset" limit="dataObject.limit" total="dataObject.total" page="dataObject.page"></itemscounter>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

  myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
    $scope.dataObject = {
       offset: 1,
       limit: 20,
       total: 25,
       page: 2
    }
})

myApp.directive("itemscounter", function() {

return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        page: '=',
        total: '=',
        offset: '=',
        limit: '=' 
    },
    template: "<div>Showing products {{offset}} to {{limit}} from {{total}} (Page {{page}})</div>",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    }
}

})
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance,

Guillermo

Comment: To help we will need to see the html that calls the directive as well.  I recommend posting your code to jsfiddle.net or a similar site and putting a link here so we can see it running.

Comment: Thanks Paul, plunker added

Comment: Thanks Guillermo.  Personally, If I were you I would leave the code on stackoverflow as well so that it can be referenced more easily.

Comment: Nice question, Guillermo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I saw wrong, based on your description and example, is that the data model was declared outside the controller scope. I created a [working version on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xJDjybloaTHvHC3zxmVw?p=preview). The only thing I changed was moving the data model into the $scope of the controller so that it could be bound to the directive by Angular.

I changed this:

```
var dataObject = {
  offset: 1,
  limit: 20,
  total: 25,
  page: 2
}

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){

})
```

to this:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
  $scope.dataObject = {
    offset: 1,
    limit: 20,
    total: 25,
    page: 2
  };
})
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Adam!, it was my fault to put it outside the scope and with var, while setting up the plunker, you were absolutely right. As the plunker works so well, I´m frustrated now because I can´t fix the issue. I´m using routing and the ng-controller directive is the main view, while the directive element is applied to the template rendered inside the ng-view...

Your answer makes me think that the dataObject is not visible when I´m calling it and it makes sense since the controller is not called inside the template itself, rather in the main view.

Comment: @Guillermo Without seeing how everything is wired together it is difficult to assess the situation, however I would caution you about using ng-controller if you are also using ng-view and routing. My understanding is that [ng-view](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive:ngView) complements the [$route service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route). Your module config will define routes containing views and controllers. I don't understand why you would still need to be using ng-controller while using routing. It sounds like you may be incorrectly using routing.

Comment: Add thanks so much for your comment. I took off ng-controller from the main view, nothing changed but it's good to make things work as it should. Your original answer pointed me to look for data issues and found it! Thanks a lot! You helped me to figure out what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your controller.

```
$scope.dataObject = dataObject;
```

See my updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jadubSID4zqYDY1PZKMJ).

Angular doesn't see code outside of it's own scopes.  So, that line adds the global javascript dataObject variable to the directive's parent scope.

Once there the

```
    scope: {
        page: '=',
        total: '=',
        offset: '=',
        limit: '=' 
    },
```

code in your directive's controller makes a 2 way binding between the $scope.dataObject variable and your page, total, offset and limit variables in your directive.

Comment: Thanks so much adam! As I was explaining to Adam, Was my fault to misplace the data object, I have it working on my original code as you described. Please see my answer to adam. thanks so so much for your time and clarity answering my question.